Github CLI - gh auth login with auth token works but does not "remember" the authenticated session
I have to perform a gh auth login frequently as it doesn't seem to remember the authenticated session. I use personal access token to login.

Any suggestions on how to avoid having to login frequently?
I do not have git credential manager setup, is that the problem?

